How to set up retention period in dbt model if it run next day need to run dag without fail
We did dbt configuration for one of the model with incremental strategy and unique key and again customer wants to setup retention period for 7day did as per requirement and logic Is working only once when we are going to run the same table with previous data  we are getting error as cannot query over table "table name" without a filter over column event date that can be used for partition elimination how to resolve this case
Tried with by adding partition and where condition in script for retention period it is working but it is not getting run next day need solution for this is there any thing to add in this script for updating the data

Can you please elaborate a bit more on the retention period of 7 days requirement?
What do you want your DBT model to achieve after first run ?
I know there is something we can set after post hook in DBT project file but need to understand your requirement clearly .
